# Wordpress wp-admin fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have just switched my website's hosting and it is giving me error in opening the wordpress admin panel page. Can any body help me out. Thankyou

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function eregi() in
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-content/plugins/google-bot-bling/google-bot-bling.php:59
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298):
>   thisismyurl_google_bot_bling_init_code('') #1
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323):
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(453):
>   WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-settings.php(448):
>   do_action('init') #4
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-config.php(104):
>   require_once('/home/atifchat/...') #5
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once('/home/atifchat/...') #6
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-admin/admin.php(31):
>   require_once('/home/atifchat/...') #7
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-admin/in in
>   /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-content/plugins/google-bot-bling/google-bot-bling.php
>   on line 59

Comment: ereg_* function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0. Maybe, your new host use php 7.

Answer (score 0):

What hosting did you switch from as well as what hosting did you switch it to? A lot of hosts for WordPress will give you support for this kind of thing especially if you just switched to their services so I would probably call support and give them the URL so that they can see the error and it is likely that they will give you some help. If they don't, try this article: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/
I remember migrating a site and having to FTP in to rename the plugins folder to plugins.hold or something and then I could login then I went back and renamed it again. But just to be safe I would follow the article and not my words.

Answer (score 0):

The `eregi()` function, actually, the entire `ereg_*` family of functions was removed entirely in PHP 7.x. According to your error log, you have a voice chat plugin still using those functions.

```
Stack trace: #0 /home/atifchat/public_html/pakistanivoicechat.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php
```

**Suggestion:** Contact plugin developer and ask them to update.